# What is the error in the following latex code

Tags: errors, pstricks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{pstricks}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{pspicture}(3,3.2)\scalebox{.9}{
\rput(2.5,0.3){
\rput(0,0){
    %\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](0,0)(10,4)
    
    \psline[linecolor=red](1,0)(.7,1)(1,2)(2.5,2)(2.8,1)(2.5,0)
    \psline[linecolor=green](1,0)(2.5,0)
    \rput(1.75,0){\arrow{0}{green}}
    
    \psline[linecolor=red](1,2)(0.5,3)\psline[linecolor=red](2.5,2)(3,3)
        \psline[linecolor=red](-.3,1)(0.7,1)
            \psline[linecolor=red](2.8,1)(3.8,1)
    \psdot(0.5,3)\psdot(3,3)
    \psdot(1,0)\psdot(1,2)\psdot(2.5,2)\psdot(2.5,0)\psdot(-0.3,1)\psdot(3.8,1)
    
    \rput(1,-.3){$1$}\rput(2.5,-.3){$2$}\rput(2.95,1.25){$3$}
    \rput(3.8,1.25){$4$}
    \rput(2.8,2){$5$}\rput(3.3,3){$6$}\rput(.7,2){$7$}
    \rput(.2,3){$8$}\rput(.55,1.25){$9$}\rput(-.4,1.25){$10$}
    \rput(1.65,-.6){$U$}
    }   

\rput(6,0){
%\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](0,0)(10,4)

\psline[linecolor=green](1,0)(.7,1)
    \rput(.85,0.5){\arrow{105}{green}}
    \psline[linecolor=blue](.7,1)(1,2)
        \psline[linecolor=blue](1,2)(2.5,2)
            \psline[linecolor=blue](2.5,2)(2.8,1)
                \psline[linecolor=green](2.8,1)(2.5,0)
                    \rput(2.65,0.5){\arrow{-105}{green}}
                
\psline[linecolor=green](1,0)(2.5,0)
\rput(1.75,0){\arrow{180}{green}}

    \psline[linecolor=green](.7,1)(2.8,1)
        \rput(1.75,1){\arrow{0}{green}}

\psline[linecolor=red](1,2)(0.5,3)
\psline[linecolor=red](2.5,2)(3,3)
\psline[linecolor=red](-.3,1)(0.7,1)
\psline[linecolor=red](2.8,1)(3.8,1)
\psdot(0.5,3)\psdot(3,3)
\psdot(1,0)\psdot(1,2)
\psdot(2.5,2)\psdot(2.5,0)
\psdot(-0.3,1)\psdot(3.8,1)

\rput(1,-.3){$2$}\rput(2.5,-.3){$1$}\rput(2.95,1.25){$4$}
\rput(3.8,1.25){$3$}
\rput(2.8,2){$6$}\rput(3.3,3){$5$}\rput(.7,2){$8$}
\rput(.2,3){$7$}\rput(.5,1.25){$10$}\rput(-.3,1.25){$9$}
\rput(1.65,-.6){$U^+$}
}}  
}\end{pspictute}
\caption{Unicyclic $3$-colored digraph whose inverse is not unicyclic}\label{h2}
    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here in this code, I am not getting the output. Please help regarding this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: To start with, your code isn't compilable because it fails to load the `graphicx` package (to define `\scalebox` and because `\begin{pspicture}` is  terminated by `\end{pspictute}`. That would be two good reasons for why you're not getting any output.

Comment: You are correct. that \arrow message I am getting. How to get rid of from that

Comment: @user244706 how can we know? Firstly if that is the error message that you want help with, fix your posted code so that it produces that error. Secondly your question  is essentially "I have `\zzffaaw` in my document and get undefined command  `\zzffaaw` " you could fix it by removing the undefined command. If you think that command should do something say what you want it to do and perhaps someone could suggest a definition. If you copied this code from somewhere the `\arrow` would be defined there so you need to copy its definition from there.

Comment: Ok. I have understood. Thank you